# Choosing a DigitalOcean Droplet (VM) for a Huge Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster

Where do I begin? I have a Docker compose e.g. that has a JHipster UAA container, a JHipster Registry, a JHipster Gateway (my custom web app), and 5 JHipster Microservices. I can form a docker compose with everything and say 2 microservices and run the system/application (docker-compose) on my Macbook Pro successfully. I can't run everything on my MacBook Pro with or without volumes.

DigitalOcean has Kubernetes and I thought about that but their features don't even include auto-scaling yet. I would just like to run the entire system on DigitalOcean using docker-compose and scale in the future "as-needed". Where do I begin? Or, where do I start?

I've created huge infrastructure on AWS in two availability zones with VPC and Security, load-balancers, and network configurations, using Terraform, but ... I don't know where to start using Docker. Do I just create a VM, try it, and then if it doesn't work, destroy and try the next size up? Also, is it feasible to configure Docker and docker-compose to actually run my entire system on a Macbook Pro with 16GB of RAM?

I need some pointers on how I should be thinking. I want to get this automated to production as soon as I can. And, I understand I can customize and configure each container after I create it for docker-compose, but I don't know how to determine what needs tweaking really.

Help.

David L. Whitehurst